# How to make a DependencyProperty properly coerce a value's type for a binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've got an `ItemsControl` subclass that behaves like a `Selector`, but it can't be a subclass of `Selector` because the selected item isn't necessarily in the `Items` collection. So I'm stuck reimplementing a lot of `Selector` stuff.

My class has a `SelectedValuePath` property. If that property has a value, I create a binding so that when `SelectedItem` changes, the value of `"SelectedItem." + SelectedValuePath` gets assigned to `SelectedValue`. This works perfectly -- as long as the consumer binds my `SelectedValue` to a property *of the same type* as the value property on `SelectedItem`.

**Here's the problem:**

However, if the selected item has an `int ID` property that's being used as a value property, and `SelectedValue` is bound to a `Nullable<int> SelectedID` property on a view model, the binding fails to set the property on the view model except in the case where `SelectedItem` is null.

I've noticed that the WPF `ComboBox` class doesn't have this problem, so it must be solvable without requiring the consumer to provide a value converter. I've tried a `CoerceValueCallback` and that doesn't do anything for me. It doesn't know the target type. It has no information about the binding that's receiving the value.

What is `ComboBox.SelectedValue` doing that I'm not?

I'm reasonably familiar with `IValueConverter` and how value converters are added to bindings in XAML at the point where a control is used. I don't need help with that. I'm asking if anybody knows how any binding on `ComboBox.SelectedValue` converts `int` to `int?` without the consumer of the control adding a value converter to the binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I should have expected, the problem wasn't where I expected. There was no type conversion issue.

It appears that the problem was internal to my class. I was updating `SelectedValue` with a binding.

```
Binding binding = new Binding("SelectedItem." + SelectedValuePath);
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
binding.Source = this;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, MenuComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, binding);
```

This appears to have interfered with the consumer's two-way binding to `SelectedValue`.

I have a `BindingTarget` class which derives from `DependencyObject`. It exposes a single `DependencyProperty` called `Value`, and fires an event when `Value` changes. I already wrote it to forward values to the "read only" `DependencyProperty` `SelectionBoxItem`, where the setter is protected. So instead of creating a binding from `"SelectedItem."+SelectedValuePath` with `SelectedValue` as the target as above, I used a private `BindingTarget` instance as the target, and set `SelectedValue` in its `ValueChanged` handler. The consumer's binding now works as expected.

```
//  The type argument to BindingTarget is the type of the property. 
_selectedValueBindingTarget = new BindingTarget<Object>();

_selectedValueBindingTarget.ValueChanged += (s, e2) =>
{
    SelectedValue = e2.NewValue;
};

Binding binding = new Binding("SelectedItem." + SelectedValuePath);
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
binding.Source = this;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(_selectedValueBindingTarget, 
    BindingTarget<Object>.ValueProperty, binding);
```